# Calling javascript class methods from another method inside the same class

Tags: javascript

I don't know how to deal properly with this case. I have a Javascript object like this:

```
var myClass = {

    init : function(){
        $("button").on("click" , this.func1);
    },

    func1: function(){

        // do stuffs

        this.func2();

    },

    func2: function(){

        // do stuffs
    }
}

myClass.init();
```

When I initialize my class for binding event there's no problem. In the init function, the value of `this` is the class itself, so I can call their methods without problem.

Take into account that when a button is clicked, I executed `func1`. I found the problem inside the function `func1` because in this case the value of `this` is the button that was pressed, so when I try `this.func2` I get `Uncaught TypeError: this.func2 is not a function`.

**How I deal with this kind of problem?** I'm sure that there is a standar way to solve this problem but I don't know it.

Thanks !!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to access the correct \`this\` / context inside a callback?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-context-inside-a-callback)

Comment: You are writting literal objects (`obj = { foo: 'bar' }`). I recommend to you to make prototype normal objects (`obj = function() { this.foo = function() { return "bar"; }; };`)

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude thank you su much for your advice! could you give me some link for deeping in what you say? please

Comment: Yes, of course. You can see something here: https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Trabajando_con_objectos || https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Object/prototype

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From your example, `this.func1` is actually bound to no context when it is executed. So its `this` keyword will be either fallbacked to `window` object on `legacy mode` or `undefined` on `strict mode`. In order to execute `this.func1` in `myClass` context, you can use one of these methods:

1. Set `this` to `myClass` with [Function.prototype.bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind)

   ```
   $("button").on("click", this.func1.bind(this));
   ```
2. Wrap inside an anonymous function

   ```
   var self = this;
   $("button").on("click", function() {
     self.func1();
   });
   ```
3. Wrap inside an [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

   ```
   $("button").on("click", () => this.func1());
   ```

Comment: should I change something inside the `func1` implementation?

Comment: @LuisGonzález no, you just need to bind it here. He did not explain it, that's the problem.

Comment: Thank you so much! Your answer fixed magically the bug. I didn't know about the `bind` function!

Comment: @LuisGonzález you might want to have a look at the first answer in the doublicate link. It has some nice additional Infromation about all that

Comment: yes I am having a look and I am thinking that this answer could be a duplicate

Comment: @LuisGonzález You can check my answer for more details.

Comment: I didn't know this JS sentence `() => this.func1()` thank you for this great answer

Comment: @LuisGonzález Just make sure your targeted browsers support arrow functions. It's a quite new feature.

Comment: @LuisGonzález yes that is only ECMA Script 2015, the latest version, not enabled in browsers by default yet.

Comment: @Tresdin nice! now you deserve my upvote ;) (maybe add a ES6 warning to arrow functions)

Comment: @Tresdin if `func1` would require a parameter, how could I pass it if I am binding it a context? what should I change in this code line `this.func1.bind(this)`?

Comment: @LuisGonzález It's already described in the link. `this.func1.bind(this,arg1,arg2,...)`

Comment: Thanks! I was reading it but it didn't works... after I noticed what was the problem